# Reload Icecast2 config without stopping ongoing stream?

Tags: configuration, icecast

I'm currently working on making an Icecast2 server with multiple users. At some points, I will have to reload the configuration file, but I don't want to disrupt any currently ongoing streams. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use that command:

`/etc/init.d/icecast2 reload`

This will not disrupt any currently ongoing streams. 
But, in my experience, not all configuration changes will be applied, using that command. For example, I could succesfully update the `<mount></mount>` list (add new mount points), but in order to update some other settings, like `<burst-size>` I needed to restart the Icecast server completely using:

`/etc/init.d/icecast2 restart`

Comment: I can confirm `reload` working for `<mount>` settings, which is what most people need anyway. for settings in `<limits>`or network related settings a `restart` is needed.

Comment: In my case both above commands not working I am getting **error** `-bash: etc/init.d/icecast2: No such file or directory` and I used to start this `/opt/icecast/latest/bin/icecast -c /opt/icecast/latest/etc/icecast.xml -b`

Comment: You're missing the leading slash - `etc/init.d/icecast2` should be `/etc/init.d/icecast2` but as your comment was nearly 2 years ago you probably figured that out by now :D

Answer (score 2):

Icecast will reload its configuration on SIGHUP on all Unix/Linux systems. (For Windows reloading it will be possible starting with 2.5 through web interface)

Please note, that you should ensure that the configuration file is valid.

You might also want to have a look at URL authentication and default mountpoints in version 2.4.1
http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#url
It allows you to offload many aspects to a back end system.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I've just discovered something that is a bit flawed with regards to reload config files...

```
/etc/init.d/icecast2 reload
```

...will indeed reload your config file without breaking the audio stream, and it will also update the mount points, but what it doesn't do is cut off anybody that was connected to a previously existing mount point still using an old password.

I have a situation where I'm generating a different icecast config file for each live dj.

`/live` is the mount point in the the config and this never changes, but the password does every time I reload the config file.

If a previous dj is connected using `password1` on `/live` and then the new config is loaded changing the password of `/live` to `password2`, it won't automatically disconnect the previous dj still using `password1`.

The only way to do it is by...

```
/etc/init.d/icecast2 restart
```

... which as I'm sure you're all aware is horrible as it introduces a 1 -2 second break in the audio stream while it restarts.

Comment: Seems more then logical since authentication is only done before connecting to the stream and not during.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but the command "/etc/init.d/icecast2 restart" did not produce a break in the audio for me using icecast 2.4.4.  Perhaps this was an improvement made since last year when this discussion was happening.  Also, my server has a very light load (only me listening at the moment) so I'm sure your mileage may vary if you have to restart a heavily loaded server.